# How could i retrieve data from firebse realtime database in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

I am saving data of different users in their uid node and in uid node i have generated different keys in which i have saved data. I my trying to retrieve email,username from keys node.
I have tried to fetch email,username using this code:-
`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    rootRef.child('Manager').child(loggedInUser.uid).child(accountKey);
    rootRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
     var value= snap.value;
     print(value['username']);
    }
    );
  }
```

`
but i am getting a null value.
How could i retrieve email, username and display it to Text widget.

Comment: did you try rootRef.child('Manager').child(loggedInUser.uid).child(accountKey).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
     var value= snap.value;
     print(value['username']);
    }
    );

Comment: Yes i tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `FutureBuilder()` since the `uid` will be null in the above code, therefore create a method that will return a `Future<DataSnapshot>`:

```
   Future<DataSnapshot> getData() async{
     var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Manager').child(user.uid).child(accountKey);
    return await dbRef.once();
  }
```

Then use it inside `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
```